# Propertyinfo get value non static value requires target

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

Im trying to reflect some data from my properties and im having a hard time trying to figure out why im getting the error "non static value requires target" I have tried passing values into getvalue with no success. if i step through the code the properties are there, do not understand why the get vlue is throwing an error.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> argument in actionArguments)
{
    Type type = argument.Value.GetType() as Type;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    Parallel.ForEach(properties, property =>
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string text = property.GetValue(null, null) as string; -- error 
            string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an instance property doesn't exist without an instance. So it is not possible to get a value of an instance property without providing an instance.If you are looking for `static` properties use `BindingFlags.Static` with `GetProperties`.

If you have an instance you need to pass it to `GetValue` method instead of *null*:

```
string text = property.GetValue(argument.Value) as string;
```

Comment: i do have an instance in argument

Comment: yes!! i literally just realized that when you mentioned it thanks

Comment: what is argument here?